# Add master record into table before create is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a `Project` and a `List` models. A List model [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) (thus, every list can contain other lists as children).

```
# Project model
has_many :lists

# List model 
belongs_to :project
acts_as_tree
```

**The problem:** 
I want to include every newly created list, that doesn't has a `parent_id` specified, into some 'master list' by default, but I don't know how to ensure that the master list will always exist. 
**Possible solution:**
I think that I need to override `project.lists.create` to create a master list(if it doesn't exist) first, and only then let the new list creation. 

I'm not sure how to do all of this properly and gracefully. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

---

I have tried the following and failed, because the `create` is called over and over, it's an infinite recursion:

```
# List model
before_create :create_master_list

private

def create_master_list
  self.project.lists.where(id: 9999).first_or_create do |master_list|
    master_list.id = 9999
  end
end
```

Error output when typing `Project.find(1).lists.create` into rails console:

```
SELECT  `lists`.* FROM `lists` WHERE `lists`.`id` = 1000 AND `lists`.`id` = 1000 AND `lists`.`id` = 1000 AND `lists`.`id` = 1000 AND `lists`.`id` = 1000 AND ...
```

Comment: You can define a "master list" as `.where(parent_id: nil)`, can't you? :)

Comment: @D-side I need it to be an actual list, so I can retrieve an entire tree by calling `get_sub_tree(root)` (where `get_sub_tree` is a custom method that retrieves all the children of passed in node)

Comment: You can modify this method to treat `root` set to `nil` like this, to fetch lists with no parent set. I'm not insisting however, it's your design choice.

Comment: @D-side I know, but it would not be an elegant solution and the code would become confusing, imho. Thanks for the advice, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the master list on the after_create hook of the project that way you make sure its always there

In the project model something along the lines

```
#Project Model
after_create :create_master_list

  private
    def :create_master_list
      List.new(project_id: self.id, master: true)
    end

#List model
before_create :add_to_master_list, if: "parent_id.nil?"

private
def :add_to_master_list
  self.parent_id = get_project_master_list.id
end

def get_project_master_list
  return self.project.lists.where(master: true).first_or_create
end
```

Comment: If initially an orphan list(whose parent_id = nil) is created and the master_list - afterwards, the initial list will stay orphaned

Comment: You will still need to add to add the list to master list in the before create of the list I was mainly focusing on making sure the master list always exists.

Comment: Is there a scenario where you create the lists before project?

Comment: So if the main flow goes like: project has only one master list and any list created without parent id should go to this master list the code could be like my updated answer

Comment: Your method is a partial solution, because if master list gets accidentally deleted, it won't be recreated by default, thus it can potentially introduce some nasty bugs

Comment: If master list gets deleted accidentally all its children lists will be deleted too it should be protected from being deleted.

Comment: I have accounted for the scenario of master list being deleted. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord's [`first_or_create`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) might be what you're looking for. It will create and return a new record if none exists.

```
project.lists.where(parent_id: nil).first_or_create
```

Comment: I did what you suggested, but ran into an error. See an updated question please, and thanks for the answer